# What does ItemObject property of TNewCheckListBox class do and how to use it properly? (Inno Setup)

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

We have a class called `TNewCheckListBox` and it has this property:

```pascal
property ItemObject[Index: Integer]: TObject; read write;
```

What is it for and how to use it properly?

Also, there are 3 methods of this class:

```pascal
function AddCheckBox(const ACaption, ASubItem: String; ALevel: Byte; AChecked, AEnabled, AHasInternalChildren, ACheckWhenParentChecked: Boolean; AObject: TObject): Integer;
function AddGroup(ACaption, ASubItem: String; ALevel: Byte; AObject: TObject): Integer;
function AddRadioButton(const ACaption, ASubItem: String; ALevel: Byte; AChecked, AEnabled: Boolean; AObject: TObject): Integer;
```

What is `AObject: TObject` parameter used for? I'd like to have an example if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

When you add an item to the list, the `AObject` parameter is assigned internally to **Obj** :

```pascal
ItemState.Obj := AObject;
```

where `ItemState` represents single item (line) in the `TNewCheckListBox`:

```pascal
  TItemState = class (TObject)
  public
    Enabled: Boolean;
    HasInternalChildren: Boolean;
    CheckWhenParentChecked: Boolean;
    IsLastChild: Boolean;
    ItemType: TItemType;
    Level: Byte;
    Obj: TObject;
    State: TCheckBoxState;
    SubItem: string;
    ThreadCache: set of Byte;
    MeasuredHeight: Integer;
    { Force update item flag }
    FUpdate: Integer;
  end;
```

And that

```pascal
property ItemObject[Index: Integer]: TObject; read write;
```

is used to read/write this object during runtime.

I assume this `Obj` is used for storing any object the developer wants (useful when you need to store specific data related to the item), similar to the C# `Tag` property on `Control`.

Basically it is up to you what you use this property for.